# NullPointExeception android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to get the User Email by login from `Firebase-Auth` and print that Email to the TextView on my NavBar. But everytime i run and I get NullPointException error on my TextView.
What goes wrong?

**Get User Email**

onCreate Method

```
    emailHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailHeader);
    fire = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = fire.getCurrentUser();
    String email = user.getEmail();

    if(fire.getCurrentUser() != null){
        String EMAIL = fire.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        emailHeader.setText(EMAIL);
        //Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Email Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Layout**

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/emailHeader"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
```

[NullPointExeception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QS2X.png)

Comment: did you do emailHeader = findViewById(R.id.emailHeader); ?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque yes.. Sorry i will update my Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why it occur because I have similar application like you running the `firebase-auth` and it occur sometimes. But `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project work for me.

try and check it out.